# Send statistics when using Magento / Prestashop module

Tags: magento, google-analytics, prestashop, usage-statistics

I'm trying to create a module for Magento and Prestashop. Does anyone know if there is a way to send me statistic (Google Analytic or something else) when people are using my module? I was thinking about a Google Analytic push.

It's mostly to keep people up to date about new release. 
Does anyone has done that before? Is it OK to do that if you explain it in the marketplace where you can find the module?

I'm not sure a module is authorize to do that. I haven't found this information in the terms & conditions of the marketplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeaaah it's not exactly compliant with marketplace policies for either Magento or Prestashop.

Your best bet is to embed your own tracker or - better - your own Google Tag Manager snippet. Either way, make sure you name them specifically so as not to conflict with your users current implementation of GA and/or Google Tag Manager